# Access SQL Server Localhost database, from an external web service?

Tags: sql, sql-server, localhost, remote-access

I have the next setup for SQL Server on my machine =>
And I'm able to login from SSMS with the next data=>

```
Server Type: Database Engine
Server Name: DESKTOP-9J8RFVD\SQLEXPRESS
Login: SamLProgrammer
Password: 12345
```

When I open this Server in the SSMS, and I go to databases. I can find a database that I created from SQLCMD named "myDatabase".

However I'm trying to connect to that database from an external connector called "Skyvia"

And it requires the next data:

[image]

But as you can see, I throws an error labelled as 26 -error. And I still don't get why. That is my IP address, I queried from "whatismyip.com".

I have also opened ports through windows firewall. And enabled TCP/IP and ALLIP ass follows:

[image]

But I still don't know what configuration I'm missing. Please I would be really glad to any help

New edits:

[image]

I used the number 1 ip address to open my router port 1433. I dont know if that should be the right one to use.

[image]

Comment: `tcp:181.131.99.9\DESKTOP-9J8RFVD\SQLEXPRESS`? Do you understand that the backslash is used to delimit the server name (or IP address) from the instance name? Have you tried simply `tcp:181.131.99.9\SQLEXPRESS`?

Comment: Have you opened all of the required firewall ports? (Not just on your PC but also on your network router?) Connections using instance names like this require not only access to the TCP port that the instance is listening on (seems like tcp/50534 in your screen shot) but also to udp/1434 so that instance name resolution using an SSRP request to the SQL Browser Service can be successful. Alternatively you could dodge the instance name and just connect to its port directly with `tcp:181.131.99.9,50534`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yep, I have opened them in the router. But It asks for an IP, I used the ethernet one and the port 1433, TCP in the router. 

But the ip I used to open the ports in the router, I think is the local one, I dont know if I should use the public one*

I have tried only with  the both ways you told me, And for the one with the dynamic port throws me: "the wait operation timed out: err -0"

And the other method  using just /SQLEXPRESS, gives me the same -26 error code. I have updated my question with the router setup

Comment: That's cute bit you're probably behind your isp nat etc, so you will never be able to get through all the hoops. You're supposed to get your db in the cloud or using some other public facing server, not a local comp

Comment: @siggemannen Yep I know its just that I need to do a demo and the demo needs to be on local. Before moving it to a hosted web server

Comment: Just be careful exposing your ip etc. I'd delete this question if i were you :)

Answer (score 0):

At the very end, this was the way it worked for me tcp:,

[image]